# MySQL Replace multiple from_str to reduce nesting

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to reduce nesting on a multiple replace? something like `('\'', '(', ')')` on the *from_str* code like

```
SET NEW.uri = REPLACE(REPLACE(lower(NEW.event), ' ', '-') ,('\'', '(',')'), '')
```

I know below will work but trying to get away from all the nesting

```
SET NEW.uri = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(lower(NEW.event), ' ', '-') ,'(','') , ')' , '') ,'\'', '');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's as far as I can find still no more straight forward way to write the query with the built in operators.

If you're using the same construct in many places (or with a great number of REPLACE) and you want a simpler way to express it, you could of course [write your own function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-function.html) to do what you need.

Comment: Thanks Joachim, I can't find a better way to write the query either, agree about the function.